# Cannot mutate default parameter list of derived class

Tags: python, python-2.7

The is a minimized script I have:

```
import random

def genvalue():
    return random.randint(1, 100)

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x = genvalue()):
        self.x = x

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()

t1 = A(10)
t2 = B()
t3 = B()

print t1.x
print t2.x
print t3.x
```

The expected result I wanted is t1.x having the value 10, and the other two having random values, but instead both t2 and t3 have the same values, it is like the genfunc is only called once. I would like to have it called each time when an instance is initiated. Is it possible to do it without messing with the function signatures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`genfunc` is only called once - when the class description is read for the first time. The parameter is evaluated there - it's not evaluated each time the class is created.

Instead set the default value to None, and if a value isn't given, generated it in your `__init__` method instead.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x=None):
        if x is None:
            x = genvalue()

        self.x = x
```

Answer (score 3):

Default arguments are evaluated at *callable creation time*.

Currently, `genvalue` is called exactly once in your program, at the time the method `__init__` is being being built in order to bind the default value of `x` to the method.

Demo:

```
import random

def genvalue():
    print('genvalue called')
    return random.randint(1, 100)

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x=genvalue()):
        self.x = x

print('creating some instances...')
A()
A()
A()
print(A.__init__.__defaults__)
```

Output:

```
genvalue called
creating some instances...
(32,)
```

Use

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x=None):
        self.x = x if x is not None else genvalue()
```